# Check if number exists in sublist and return indexes of sublist in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Input:

```
[['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['7', '8'], ['2', '6'], ['9', '10'], ['10', '2'], ['3', '5']]
```

Output (for 2):

```
[0, 1, 5, 7] # 2 exists in these sublists which has 0, 1, 5, 7 indexes in main list
```

Comment: Do you want to check for 2 or '2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this cleanly with a list comprehension.

```
nested_list = [['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['7', '8'], ['2', '6'], ['9', '10'], ['10', '2'], ['3', '5']]


indices = [
    index
    for index, list_ in enumerate(nested_list)
    if '2' in list_
]

print(indices)
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: not exactly 2, i need it dynamically. but i got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can trying this:

```
def my_check(l,k):
    res=[]
    for i in l:
        if k in i:
            res.append(l.index(i))
    return res
l=[['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['7', '8'], ['2', '6'], ['9', '10'], ['10', '2'], ['3', '5']]
print(my_check(l,'2'))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.